# Natbib citations do not show the full author name

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using the `ucthesis` class with `natbib` package. None of the `\cite`, `\citet` and `\citep` commands, show the full author name. They just show the very last part of the author's name in the bib file
Example

```
@article{bj1996,
    author = {Bjornstad J.F.},
    title = "On the generalization of the likelihood function and likelihood principle",
    year = "1996",
    journal="Journal of the American Statistical Association"
    volume = "91",
    number = "36",
    pages = "791-806"
}

\cite{bj1996}\\
\citep{bj1996}
\citet{bj1996}
```

prints

```
J.F. [1996]
[J.F., 1996]
J.F. [1996]
```

Just the last part of the author's name.
Any idea why?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I think that should be `{Bjornstad, J.F.}` or `{J.F. Bjornstad}` in the .bib file. Otherwise bibtex interprets Bjornstad as the frist name and J.F. as the last name.

Answer (score 2):

You should follow the BibTeX Author formatting explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX#Author_formatting

Specially, you are interested in:

> Multiple word last names are distinguished from first and middle names
>   by placing the last names first, then a comma, then the first and
>   middle names

so you should write this as `author = {Bjorstad, J. F.}`, being Bjorstad the last name, and J. F. the first name.

Comment: This explanation is likely to be quite confusing: In the example, the last name does *not* consist of multiple words. Please consider simplifying your explanation.

Comment: That is what I am doing author = {Bjorstad, J. F.}, It is just not working., Changing the order works though {J. F.,Bjorstad } in the article but in the references at the end , it prints the first name first name and I want the last name to be the first.

Comment: It should be {J. F. Bjorstad} then. With NO commas.